# String s = ...;

Tags: java

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
String s = ...;
BufferedWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(file, charset);
    writer.write(s, 0, s.length());
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
} finally {
    if (writer != null) writer.close();
}
```

I came across this snippet in a Java tutorial.but what does the following do?

```
String s = ...;
```

If the question too silly, please don't mind I am new Java programmer.Thank you in advance.

Comment: its a definite compile time error, it'd never compile

Comment: Link to said tutorial? This is taken out of context, but most likely the authoer was implying that any String s can be used. The literal code above will not compile.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html

Comment: @ArijitSaha: Just check more code snippet from the same link. They have also use `try(...) and Path source = ...;`

Answer (score 3):

`String s = ...;` means any string with arbitrary value (but not `null`).

That's called **Ellipsis**:

> a series of dots that usually indicate an intentional omission of a
>   word, sentence or whole section.

The intention was to show how `BufferedWriter` works and not how to initialize a `String` instance and that's why `String s = ...;` was used.

Answer (score 2):

It is just an example. You have to fill the string `s` with some seasonable string. Eg.: `String s = "blaBLABLAblabla!";`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming it's simply a case of:

```
String s = "type whatever you like here";
```

Answer (score 0):

Its do nothign only gives compile time error , You have to define something for it before run

```
String s = "My value to be test";
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you can add any String of your own in the place of ..., e.g."This is my answer"
There's nothing "..." in java.